# Cannot install .apk file on emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, emulation

**The Issue:**
I'm using Android Studio on Win8 platform to develop my new android application. I can upload and install the apk on my physical device (Samsung Galaxy S4-mini Dous) with no problem. But, when I want to upload and install it on Emulator, it gets stock and wait for ever!

**What I have done:**
- I used Eclipse to see if the issue is related to Android Studio, but the same result.
- I increased the ADB connection timeout value; no success.
- I used adb in command-line mode tp install the package; no success again.
- Searched through StackOverflow site (and some other sites) to see if there is any answer to similar issue,  didn't help.

**My Situation:**
Actually AVD is needed to run some optimization tools (which is not working for physical devices). I would appreciate if somebody can help me fixing this issue.

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: how did you set up your avd? did you use a tutorial?

Comment: Is the emulator open (as in completely started up) before you try installing the app?

Comment: - The avd is installed during Android Studio installation.

Comment: Yes, the emulator is completely up, and I can open the default apps on it (like calculator).

Comment: Try creating a new virtual device and use it instead of whatever one you are using currently in the AVD manager. Play around with several to see if it was that particular device causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I had created 4 to 5 different virtual devices with different RAM size, but no gain. Sorry that I forgot to mention it in my original Ask.

Answer (score 0):

I came up against this recently.  Turns out I was running out of internal storage on my emulator.  Edited the configuration and increased internal storage and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try different emulators, using different versions of Android, and different versions of the processor architecture. And of course, there must be enough space on the emulator.

It helped me.

There may also be problems accessing the file.

On Mac view permission (in terminal):  `ls -@ fileName.apk`

On Mac change permission (in terminal):  `chmod 777 fileName.apk`